# Problem starting with Java - Polish letters in computer Username ( Visual Studio Code )

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I just want to start learning programing in JAVA but I have problem with Visual Studio Code. It's not reading Polish letters in directory line. I'm posting a screenshot.

[image]

Is there any way to fix that without reinstalling the system?

Comment: Please post your console output as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try to remove the space in the path name

Comment: The second part of my username is my surname. So there will be space between. I can't change it without reinstalling system.

Comment: @Priez. You can search online about how to change account name and don't need to reinstall system